# Concerning the meaning of "week for week, month for month, year for year"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Does the expression in bold within:

> “The human ability to understand capitulates when faced with the sheer number of deaths, **week for week, month for month, year for year**,” Judge Bührmann said. Going through the names of each patient, their medical records and the details of how and when they had died left him feeling “like a bookkeeper of death,” he said.

mean:

> week *after* week, month *after* month, year *after* year

?

Source: The 9th paragraph of [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/06/world/europe/germany-nurse-killed-patients.html) newspaper article.

Comment: Please cite a detailed source for this quote.  Ideally you should link to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in this context that means "week after week, month after month, year after year". I might have written "week by week ..." with the same meaning.

It is worth noting that this is a translation, the judge apparently spoke in German. The use of "for" may echo a usage that is normal or idiomatic in German, but unusual if translated literally into English.